# Number formatting in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to format a number in a `GridView` that is in pounds into pence.

> e.g. 0.0106 to 1.06

Is it possible to archive this with the `DataFormatString` on the `GridView`? Or would it make more sense to do the conversion within the stored procedure?

Comment: i think if you want it in pence the best way is to do it in the stored procedure, because this pounds number in that case doesn't have a use.

Comment: You should do formatting on the presentation layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You like to display the number in the `GridView`, so convert it as close to the `GridView` as possible. It is definitely a presentation thing, so do it in that layer of your application.

Using the `DateFormatString` is correct as this is specifically designed to do what you wish.

Finally, my idea of conversion in the database is that conversion is not something a database was designed for.

Comment: What would be the formatting string to perform such a change?